# Under which criteria should I accept a MSc thesis?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, thesis, masters, evaluation

I am looking for MSc thesis offers, and under which criteria should I accept a position or not?

About me: my field of study is Machine Learning for Robotics applications related to space. I am also applying for PhD positions after my MSc thesis.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I always urge my students to make sure that the following criteria are fulfilled:

1. **Do I have the fundamental knowledge to complete the work?** If not, it does not mean giving up the topic but objectively assessing how much effort I need to gain the necessary knowledge.
2. **Do I understand the problem?** The problem has to be well defined because, in the end, you will have only 6 months. You need in this case to know what is the input and what is the output you aim to reach. Also, how you go from *input* to *output* (I mean methodology).
3. **Do I have a realistic time plan?** Initially, it does not have to be very detailed but you need to have a time estimation of every task. For example, if you will need data collection and labelling, you will need to count several weeks for that. Will this be considered a significant contribution? Ask your supervisor. Will I have enough time to implement my approach? Estimate it yourself.
4. **Are there any related work?** It is very unrecommended to start something that was not investigated before (i.e. unlikely in ML) because the goal is not to start from scratch but to push the state-of-the-art. When you have a concrete state of research from which you are going to start, the task will be much easier and you won't struggle a lot.
5. **Is the supervisor expert in this area?** Researchers try always to extend their research interests and their first attempts are with theses. This is completely normal but if the domain expertise of the supervisor is far from the thesis topic, you will have to consider that you might have weak supervision.

I would also recommend:

1. Do not underestimate the difficulty of the problem neither overestimate your capability to solve it. I noticed that most of the students tend to make the problem more difficult than what was proposed by the supervisor. When the supervisor is less seasoned in a specific sub-domain (which happens a lot), it will be problematic.
2. Before you start, spend as much time as you need to prepare a good proposal that should contain: a) problem statement, b) motivation, c) state of research, d) proposed methodology, e) baseline approaches, f) evaluation scheme.

Comment: 3b. Do **they** have a realistic time plan?